# in database table ,getting records based on one column value and that value is based on other two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
 username | timestamp   | distance_location1 | distance_location2
  jack     1532101253000   22.2541(km)           152.652(km)
```

and query which i am using is

```
 select * 
 from   table 
 where  timestamp >= (select min(distance_location1) from table 
   AND  timestamp <= (select min(distance_location2) from table
```

I want to get the records based on timestamp column.

starting value of timestamp is where minimum distance_location1.

and ending value of timestamp is where minimum distance_location2

above query is not working as it gives 0 records

Comment: You're missing closing parentheses at the ends of the two subqueries.  Is that a typo?  Can add some sample data to your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its not about typo . i added one sample row. like that i m having thousands of records.

Comment: @stackoverflow . . . You are comparing timestamps to distances.  That logic just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If   distance_location1 is data type is timestamp then below query will work
where your you put  parenthesis in wrong place

```
select * 
     from   table 
     where  timestamp >=
      ( select min(distance_location1 from table )
       AND  timestamp <= (select min(distance_location2 from table)
```

But if distance_location1 and distance_location2 is not datatype timestamp

```
select * from table
where timestamp>= (select min(timestamp)  from table t where t.distance_location1=(select min(distance_location1) from table)
) and

 timestamp<=( select min(timestamp)  from table t where t.distance_location2=(select min(distance_location2) from table))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare *timestamps*, not *distances*.  In Oracle, you can use `keep` and analytic functions:

```
select t.* 
from (select t.*,
             min(timestamp) keep (dense_rank first over order by distance_location1) as distance_location1_timestamp,
             min(timestamp) keep (dense_rank first over order by distance_location2) as distance_location2_timestamp
      from table t
     ) t
where timestamp >= distance_location1_timestamp and
      timestamp <= distance_location2_timestamp;
```